# Introduction on writing launch files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
At now I finished to develop my own ROS application, I want to install my app. as the ROS package, my app. created from rosbuild, and is there any tutorial to guide how to write the launch file? I want make my own launch file including the openni_camera and the kobuki driver.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197522/introduction-on-writing-launch-files/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First I recommend to learn from old wisdom that was opened 3 years ago: [launch file how to write it](http://answers.ros.org/question/12216/launch-file-how-to-wite-it/).

What the wises there might have not mentioned is this tutorial: [Roslaunch tips for large projects](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects), which introduces very good practices on how to write reusable launch files even for smaller application.

You may also want to look into existing launch files to learn how to accomplish what you want that may not be obviously explained in the docs. There are tons of launch files installed on your machine that you can search by e.g. `find /opt/ros/hydro -iname *.launch`.

Grammar is elaborated at http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML as noted in the link above.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2